# Add Select option dynamically in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a select list. I am populating the list using `ViewBag`.But for few cases it is required to add dynamic items to the selected list.

I am able to add those items but while those values are fetched it returns null for those newly added items.No problem with getting values for other items added using 'ViewBag'.

**HTML:**

```
 <select ng-model="JobNo" id="JobNo" name="JobNo" class="myClass" style="width:100%;"> 
          <option ng-repeat="item in JobList.Data" value="{{item.ProjectCode}}">{{item.ProjectDescription}}</option> 
 </select>
<input type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="SaveData()">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.JobList =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ProjectCode)) 
//Added new item here
$compile(angular.element($("#JobNo option")).eq(0).after($compile('<option value="ALL"> -- ALL -- </option>')($scope)));

$scope.SaveData=function () { 
                 alert($scope.JobNo); // it's show 'null' when I select "--ALL--" but no problem in other cases 
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller add new item in `Joblist.Data` array at first index, instead of DOM injection.

```
$scope.JobList =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ProjectCode)) 
//Added new item here
$scope.JobList.Data.unshift({
    ProjectCode: 'ALL',
    ProjectDescription: ' -- ALL -- '
})
```

## or

you can try add an option in html and remove option injection from controller, here is the codes,

**html**

```
<select ng-model="JobNo" id="JobNo" name="JobNo" class="myClass" style="width:100%;"> 
    <option value="ALL"> -- ALL -- </option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in JobList.Data" value="{{item.ProjectCode}}">{{item.ProjectDescription}}</option> 
</select>
<input type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="SaveData()">
```

**controller**

```
$scope.JobList =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ProjectCode)) 

$scope.SaveData=function () { 
    alert($scope.JobNo); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<select ng-options="listname for refvar in displayname track by value" ng-model="selected value's variable"></select>
```

Comment: Please can you give more explanation about why this answer is correct and how it works?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: more details and no of ways to bind select list in Angular from following link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select